# Anylogic, activate or deactivate a Delay block based on a time condition

Tags: simulation, anylogic, event-simulation

Is it possible to activate or deactivate a Delay block based on a time condition?
I wish an entity in the queue could enter into a delay block only if the current simulation time is greater/equal to a certain instant (for example when it is 13:00:00).
Thanks

Comment: use a hold block for that

Comment: Thanks Felipe, I supposed to use that block or wait but I wasn't able to implement the comparison between date/time in the if statement. Could you please teach me how to write the condition?

Comment: getHourOfDay()>=13 would be the condition

Comment: I tried to do it but it doesn't work. I used a Queue and a Hold block, so I wrote an "On at Exit" function in the Hold block because I want an agent already present in that Queue to not be able to exit from that block if it is after 13:00. My function is a simple if statement: `if (getHourOfDay() < 13) { hold.unblock(); } else { hold.block();}`. I don't know why it happens...

Comment: create an event that runs every day at 13:00 and use the same function on that event

Comment: Thanks a lot Felipe! Now it works